# How can I keep logs of all outgoing emails?

Tags: 8, emails, log-messages

I am using [SMTP Authentication Support](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) module to send emails with drupal 8.When I see `watcdog mail-log` from admin it shows only emails sent for registration or password reset, that is also with single line like `registration email send to..`. I did not found any logs related to email sent me for orders status. I have installed `devel_mail_logger` to keep logs but than I did not received those email which are listed in `devel_mail_logger` log list, any suggestion how can I keep all email logs with content & errors(if any).

Answer (score -1):

Try to use https://www.drupal.org/project/mail_safety I using it with swiftmailer module (configured with SMTP) and it works. You can configure it for store all outgoing emails.